# Mapping a column that contains a space using FileHelpers library

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have a CSV and some of the headers have spaces or symbols in, eg. Country Name or Post/Zip Code

I'm using some code like this to import it by mapping it to `CatRecord` objects:

```
FileHelperEngine<CatRecord> engine = new FileHelperEngine<CatRecord>();  
engine.Options.IgnoreFirstLines = 1;      
var files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath);  
var catRecords = engine.ReadFile(files.Single());
```

I create a field in my class but I need to tell it to map it to "Country Name".

I found another question that said use `[FieldTitle]` however no such attribute exists in the FileHelpers namespace. I'm using the latest one via NuGet (version 2 I think).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing something. The FileHelpers engine does not care about the headers because you have told it to ignore them with `IgnoreFirstLines = 1`.

It will map the first CSV column it finds to the first public field in `CatRecord`. The second column to the second field, etc.  The field names do not have to match the headers in your CSV file. (You could call them `Field1`, `Field2`, etc., if you prefer).